# Android Game an

Tags: c++, 2d, android, 3d, game-design

I want to develop an android game (3D/2D).. and I don't have any knowledge about android app development. So can you suggest some helpful and understandable resources like video tutorials or head first book that i could consult?

Also can I use C++ for the task?

Comment: Welcome to gamedev.stackexchange.com. Unfortunately "how to get started" questions are considered off topic here. Please read the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) before posting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the video tutorials of Android Application Development Tutorials of **theNewBostonAndroid** series. Its very briefly explained in detail & step by step way for android aplication development environment.

You can also check the **android** portal of stack exchange for any query or problems of android. Go to url ***android.stackexchange.com***